# How can I modify what gets copied to the Clipboard?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm copying a DataGrid to the clipboard so that it can be pasted to e.g. Excel while maintaining its format like this:

```
MyDataGrid.SelectAllCells();
MyDataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, MyDataGrid);
```

This works very nice. However, I need to add the string "MyDataGridTitle". If pasted to Excel, this should simply stand above the DataGrid.

I have tried various ways (e.g. use a DataObject) and tortured google, but to no success. I'd be thankful for a hint, tip or answer!

Comment: You can't put multiple items in the clipboard. You can use the [Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) class to copy data to the clipboard or read them. Perhaps you can read what DataGrid places there and modify it

Comment: I didn't do anything with the Clipboard yet but might it be useful to use `Clipboard.SetData` and provide an instance of `IDataObject` or `DataObject` as a parameter? You could use a complex object here that contains a header and the MyDataGrid contents. The only thing I don't know is how this object get's serialized and which serialization format is expected by Excel.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: feO2x, thanks, I've tried the DataObject, but that is not pasteable in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a *very elegant* solution, but you can try by manipulating the html string generated by your `DataGrid` (indeed when you paste in Excel, the `DataFormats.Html` format is the one which is used).

Something like this:

```
dg.SelectAllCells();
dg.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dg);

string dataGridContent = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html);
dataGridContent = dataGridContent.Replace("<TABLE>",
    String.Format("<TABLE><TR><TD colspan='{0}'>Your additional text<TD></TR>", dg.Columns.Count));

Clipboard.SetText(dataGridContent, TextDataFormat.Html);
```

Of course you can improve this code for example by using regular expressions instead of the `Replace` method.

Comment: Great! PS: when you are at my level, then this *is* a very elegant solution :o)

Comment: One thing I notice is that the resulting string is cut off at the end: the last cells are empty when copied to excel, even though there are values in the datagrid. I guess it's because there are Information about STARTHTML and ENDHTML in the string 'dataGridContent'

Comment: Ok, I'm adjusting EndHTML and EndFragment by the length of the replacing string and it's working as desired now. I'd now agree in that it's not a *very elegant* solution, but it's a solution nevertheless ;o) and I did not know that you could copy using html format. Thanks again.